# Repository can not be authenticated

Tags: 16.04, wine, ppa, repository

I was following [this thread](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-install-and-use-wine-run-windows-applications-linux) to install `wine`, but after I added the suggested repository and reloaded the sources list the following error message appeared:

```
W:The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::23 80], 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What is wrong here? Probably the messages are clear for those who can read them, but I do not want to make things messier.

Comment: What Ubuntu are you using?   If you open http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ with a browser you'll note that it only supports Trusty (14.04 LTS) now *ignoring other EOL releases*.  I also picked http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/  and it's even older.  The article was from 2015, so you should have verified that what you were adding to your system supported Xenial (16.04); they don't so you've got errors. You need to remove them now.

Comment: Thanks. I have `16.04`. I didn't get what you mean with the `extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists`: what should I remove on this regard?

Comment: Sorry, I think I got it now, and I do not get errors. If you translate your comment into an aswer, possibly saying what are the repositories I *should* have, I will be glad to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As for does a PPA support you release**

If I want to add a PPA that a howto, or web.post tells me will work with Ubuntu, some basic steps to follow could be

- go to the PPA main page

eg. https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/ppa and read the developers notes. For my example the notes are rather vague. However scrolling down I can see in the "Overview of published Packages" section a list of packages, dates of upload, uploaded by etc. This is your first clue, most dates are 2010-2012, with only a single 2013.

Your release is Ubuntu 16.04, or the Ubuntu release from 2016 April. This is a long time past 2013, so you've detected a problem here.

- go to the PPA download folder (where your machine will go)

eg. http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ I use this myself quite often (*as it involves less reading, which is why it was mentioned in the first comment*). What you'll see is a list of folders for each supported release. Ubuntu 16.04 is Xenial, so to support xenial there must be a folder for xenial, but there isn't.  The latest folder is 'raring' or 13.04, the 2013 upload in the prior section.  Problem detected here too.

**If this for my own machine, or a box I valued (eg. production)**

the main PPA page is a must, as I tend to look there at the way its written, how it's written by (even if I don't know the people, in my example its a team of 90 'active' members which gives a good feeling) and try and see if I trust this source. Here I think the PPA looks good, except it appears old...

**As for replacement sources**

I can't help here sorry. I don't know why you added the PPA, so I don't know what you are looking for so can't find a replacement.

If however instructions that told you to add this PPA are from an older release, check you actually need it. For example I added a PPA in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and 16.04 LTS for Redshift because I found the night color change helpful. Ubuntu 17.10 & 18.04 LTS however don't need it anymore; having the desired function by default.