# Problem with updating

Tags: updates, unity-tweak-tool

I am having some problems when I type

> sudo apt-get update

Error occurs saying the following

> E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
>   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Please help.

Comment: Your error line indicates you're running 18.04 (Bionic), but that PPA does not support Bionic (18.04) - so what did you expect? Check my answer on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056192/repository-can-not-be-authenticated/1056235#1056235 (repository cannot be authenticated) if you don't understand the first duplicate reference link...

Answer (score 1):

That repository [don't have a supported versions](https://launchpad.net/~freyja-dev/+archive/ubuntu/unity-tweak-tool-daily) for Bionic Beaver (18.04). It seems that it hasn't been updated since 2016-11-20 17:46.

You can just follow the [http-url](http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/) and verify by your self.