# How to install Xtreme Download Manager (XDM) in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, downloads, download-manager, idm

In order to install Xtreme Download manager, I've used the following commands based on what is said [here](https://itsfoss.com/4-best-download-managers-for-linux/).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xdman
```

But here's what I get from the terminal and I can't get it installed:

```
sepideh@sepideh-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
[sudo] password for sepideh: 
 This PPA Contains Applications for Ubuntu/Linux Mint from different sources but debianized by http://www.NoobsLab.com
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/apps
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Hit:10 https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
sepideh@sepideh-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Hit:10 https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
sepideh@sepideh-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK:~$ sudo apt-get install xdman
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xdman
sepideh@sepideh-Lenovo-ideapad-700-15ISK:~$
```

What should I do?

Comment: The X display manager (XDM) can be found in 'universe' (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xdm), but the PPA you refer to does not support Bionic (18.04) so did you check?  It was last updated in 2016-04-24 for Xenial (https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+related-packages).  I would suggest  removing the PPA (refer next comment), and find another source for what you want (and this time check it supports your release of Ubuntu before adding it..

Comment: With that PPA, 17.10 so far is the highest that they support.  You can either wait till they update it or contact them about getting it updated.  https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/apps

Comment: Refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056192/repository-can-not-be-authenticated/1056235#1056235  for details on some checks that can be performed prior to adding a PPA

Comment: @guiverc I'm pretty sure OP meant **X**treme **D**ownload **M**anager (`xdman`), not the X display manager ;-)

Comment: I don't believe this should have been dup-closed.  This is about "How to install XDMan when the PPA is no longer valid" vs. the linked-duplicate is about "How can I `apt update` when there's an outdated PPA in my sources?"  Nominated for reopening, since it received attention today via views and edits.

Answer (score 6):

Noobslab PPA no longer appears to maintain an XDMan release for current Ubuntu releases.  The last update was for Xenial Xerus. As far as I know, XDMan does not have any reliable PPA at the moment.  Instead ...

**Install using Tarball**

1. OpenJDK should have been installed already. Check via Terminal: `java --version`. If you get `Command 'java' not found` install it with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre
   ```

   and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> if asked.
2. Download the lastest XDMan release [here](https://github.com/subhra74/xdm/releases) (currently [7.2.11](https://github.com/subhra74/xdm/releases/download/7.2.11/xdm-setup-7.2.11.tar.xz) at the time of this edit).

   Note that recent releases are 64-bit only.  If you need a 32-bit release, the latest is [7.2.7](https://github.com/subhra74/xdm/releases/download/7.2.7/xdm-2018-x86.tar.xz).
3. After finishing the download open Terminal and `cd` to the download directory; for example: `cd ~/Downloads/Programs`
4. Run `tar -xvf xdm-setup-7.2.11.tar.xz` (for latest release) or `tar -xvf xdm-2018-x86.tar.xz` (for the 32-bit release).

   **NOTE**: You may not want to extract the file using FileRoller or other software, as it may not extract it appropriately.
5. Run `sudo ./install.sh`

Xtreme Download Manager is now installed on your system.

Answer (score 5):

Find the latest version (currently 7.2.11) on the [XDM Downloads Page](https://xtremedownloadmanager.com/#downloads) or the [Github releases page](https://github.com/subhra74/xdm/releases).  Adjust the filenames as needed below to download, extract, and run `install.sh`:

```
wget https://github.com/subhra74/xdm/releases/download/7.2.11/xdm-setup-7.2.11.tar.xz
tar -xvf xdm-setup-7.2.11.tar.xz
sudo sh install.sh
```

Comment: This kind of felt like a "duplicate" answer, since it covered the same thing as the original answer.  But it's just so much more concise that I think it stands on its own as a valid answer, even if the steps involved are exactly the same.